# pointers to derived members of the class

Tags: c++

if I have for example some  class `Base` and derived from it `Derived`
Also I have some list of shared pointers:

```
list<shared_ptr<Base> > list
```

I create shared pointer:

```
line 5    shared_ptr<Derived> ptr(new Derived(//some constructor));
```

my question is, can I do something like this:

```
list.push_back(ptr);
```

if Yes, can somebody explain why can I recieve an error (I receive this on the line 5)

```
no matching function for call to //here It writes me my constructor to Derived
```

thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Your problem is with the constructor of `Derived`, so why don't you show us how it is declared and how you use it?

Comment: Agreed, this should work so the problem must be in the code you haven't shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my question is, can I do something like this: `list.push_back(ptr);`

Yes - your problem has nothing to do with inheritance or smart pointers - you simply don't have the constructor declared you are trying to use.

A simple example that reproduces the error is:

```
struct X {};
X x(1);
```

Which gives you:

> no matching function for call to '`X::X(int)`'

You fix that by either constructing the instance differently or by adding the missing constructor:

```
struct X { X(int) {} };
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign a value of type `shared_ptr<Derived>` to a container of `shared_ptr<Base>`.  Try assigning pointer to `Derived` to `shared_ptr<Base>` and then adding that to the list<>:

```
class BASE {
 public:
  BASE() { }
  const char *name() const { return nameImpl(); }
 private:
  virtual const char *nameImpl() const { return "BASE"; }
};

class DERIVED : public BASE {
 public:
  DERIVED() { }
 private:
  virtual const char *nameImpl() const { return "DERIVED"; }
};


int main() {

 list< shared_ptr< BASE > > baseSequence;

 shared_ptr< BASE > basePtr(new BASE);
 baseSequence.push_back( basePtr );
 basePtr.reset(new DERIVED);
 baseSequence.push_back( basePtr );

 shared_ptr< DERIVED > derivedPtr(new DERIVED);
 baseSequence.push_back( derivedPtr ); 

 BOOST_FOREACH(const shared_ptr< BASE > &ptr, baseSequence) {
  cout << ptr->name() << "\n";
 }
 return 0;
}
```

`

Comment: I guess your first sentence meant to say *"container of `shared_ptr<Base>`"*?  This is fine, see e.g. the documentation: *"In particular, `shared_ptr<T>` is implicitly convertible [...] to `shared_ptr<U>`  where `U` is an accessible base of `T`"*.

Comment: You're correct.  I should have reviewed that example closer.  Thanks.